# Como subir un proyecto a un repositorios diferente del que se clono?

Tags: git, github, git-push, git-commit

Tengo proyecto que clone de un repositorio git, ahora quiero subirlo a mi cuenta de github para trabajarlo desde alli, la pregunta es: como lo subo a un nuevo servidor git? he intentado agregarlo pero siempre me redirige al antiguo servidor

Comment: Por què no le haces un fork, y despues clonas tu propio repo. :P

Comment: y como se hace?

Comment: en el repo hay un boton que se llama fork al lado superior derecho, aprietalo. :P

Comment: ¿Podrías indicar qué instrucciones usas para intentar agregar un nuevo servidor y cómo intentas subir a él las modificaciones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero borraa el directorio .git:

```
rm -rf .git
```

Luego inicializa un nuevo repositorio:

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m 'mensaje a enviar'
git push URL /*del repositorio donde va ha enviar; para mi caso era uno de GitHub*/
```

Answer (score 1):

Con remover el remote del repositorio clonado debería bastar.

Realizas:

```
git remote remove origin
```

Para clientes con git 1.7.10 y anteriores:

```
git remote rm origin
```

Y luego agregas el nuevo remote:

```
git remote add origin https://tunuevoremote.com/repo.git
```

Tambien se puede evitar tener que eliminar y agregar simplemente cambiando el URL del remote:

```
git remote set-url origin https://tunuevoremote.com/repo.git
```

Luego ejecutas los pasos tradicionales para hacer `push` a tus cambios y verlos en el nuevo remote.

Aunque siempre es bueno realizar un fork del repositorio.

Tomado de [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16330404/how-to-remove-remote-origin-from-git-repo)

Y deberías estar bien.

Answer (score 0):

Supongamos que clonaste jQuery:

```
git clone https://github.com/jquery/jquery.git
```

Luego en github crearte tu propio repo y quedó en

```
https://github.com/noe/jquery_reloaded
```

En tu local tienes que cambiar el remoto para apuntar a tu repo:

```
git remote --set-url origin https://github.com/noe/jquery_reloaded.git
```

Y de ahí en adelante cuando hagas `push` estarás trabajando con tu repo